# Can we use ForkJoinPool implementation with unknown batch size on which it should "join"

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, forkjoinpool

This is my first encounter with ForkJoinPool and I am trying to understand if I can convert my existing ExecutorService implementation into ForkJoinPool implementation?
Scenario:
My application needs to perform two operations for multiple threads:

- First operation does some data copy which can occur in parallel threads without breaking functionality. [**looks eligible to be FORK-like sub-task**]
- Second operation performs server restart, which can be requested only after last thread has finished copying the data. Currently underlying server app handles the logic of rejecting duplicate restart requests, if previously requested restart is still happening. [**I am trying to decide if this can be implemented as a JOIN sub-task**?]

In current implementation, we are performing both steps independently for each thread, but frequent restart requests has certain risk associated with it.

**Questions:**

1. I am unable to understand if ForkJoinPool implementation can be done, if we dont know how many active/running threads we will need to combine.
2. On what condition should we "await" to join, if we dont know how many such requests will come?
3. Should I be looking at CountDownLatch implementation instead?

Comment: This an opinion so I'll make it a comment. You can probably make the fork-join pool work but to me it sounds very unintuitive. Restarting the server is an odd join task. I think the solution where you simply spin of copying tasks and wait for a countdown latch before restarting seems much cleaner.

Comment: My challenge is still same with countdown latch approach. I don't know how many worker threads to spin for copying tasks. I am looking at other stats methods of executorService also.

Comment: Don't you know how many tasks you kick off? Not statically in advance, but when you do it (by looking at the data)?

Comment: There is a separate client app that sends requests, so my app will not know how many requests are coming. The requests are not batched, and that is why I don't have the control I need.

Comment: But then how can you know that you are done and can restart? Perhaps the client is still sending requests? Can't see how the fork/join pool would help either in that case as the join step joins the forked tasks for a job. If you have several jobs that start at different times based on different client requests I can't see how fork/join would help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That why I raised this ticket to know if there was any way to use ForkJoin or CountdownLatch without limiting the worker threads. Thanks for confirming that we need to have fixed limit.